# How to get device font size in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am facing a problem with the listview when height is bounded, so when I change the phone font size an overflow occurs and I don't want to give extra height to the container.

```
Container(
       height: fixed height goes here,
       child: ListView(
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         children: <Widget>[
           some widgets goes here...
         ],
       ),
     )
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can try to rely on textScaleFactor, by default it's `1.0`
if you change font size on Settings page of your device this value will be changed to `1.15`, `1.3` and so on (in 0.15 steps).

so you can multiply container height by this value:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SafeArea(child: Home()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
    return Center(
      child: Text('$h'), // with default settings it shows 1.0
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Thunermay Does different values of this media queryis same for all android and all ios device?

Comment: It is just the scale factor of the text scale set in the device itself. So yes, it should be same for iOS and Android

Answer (score 2):

In case your looking for the device font size (set inside the settings activity of the smartphone), you can use [textScaleFactor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/textScaleFactor.html) property of the [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) class.

```
double textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
```

Alternatively, you can get the same value like this:

```
double textScale = MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context);
```

As a heads up, all of the font sizes in Flutter are automatically scaled by this setting so if a user has their font scaled way up, you might hit some overflow errors. With that said, doing the same thing while you're debugging is an awesome way to find where your layout might overflow.

Check out the [accessibility section](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility) of the Flutter Docs for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

`textScaleFactor` has been deprecated since `v3.12.0-2.0.pre` please check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextScaler/textScaleFactor.html) for deprecated property.

We can use [scale](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextScaler/scale.html) method from `TextScaler`

Here is a sample:

```dart
  final ts = MediaQuery.textScalerOf(context);
  final res = ts.scale(1.0);
  print("Scale factor: $res");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to detect screen height and give your `Container()` height according to tha, and keep it detecting whenever `build()` method being re-called.

That's how to get a responsive height for your `Container()`

`MediaQuery()` could do that, as follow :

```
Container(
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // screen's size.height
       child: ListView(
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         children: <Widget>[
           some widgets goes here...
         ],
       ),
     )
```

Flutter says about size property :

> The size of the media in logical pixels (e.g, the size of the screen).

Comment: what I want is that the container takes exactly the height of its children not the screen's height, the solution is using 4 if else cases since the device has only 4 font sizes, but the problem is I don't know the current device font size